# Xcode 12.1 Emulator doesn't show widgets properly, how can I fix it?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

Last week Xcode updated itself automatically and then this problem occurs. There was not any problem before this update. I think this will be a bug because nothing changed on the app side.

The interesting part of this, widgets working well on real devices but looks messy in the emulator.

You can understand what I mean with this ss:

[[image: screenshot1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine with Big Sur. Interesting but the solution is install the macOS Big Sur for now. I tried 12.2 RC too but the problem was still continued.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue, I can't set opacity or the view isn't displayed. Worked fine with XCode 12, but broke with 12.1.

Comment: Yeah, I asked my friend and also he has this issue too. We tried 12.1 RC and 12.2 beta 3 too but still the same.